# Bash ignores key press after pressing Escape key

Tags: bash, keyboard

Whenever I press the escape key (ESC), bash ignores the next character that I type. Is that normal? It is very annoying, because I have a habit of pressing escape redundantly from using vim, where I use it to return from insert mode to normal mode.

Why does bash behave this way and how can I turn it off?

Comment: How quickly after the Escape key do you press the next key?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It is literally that any next key is ignored, no matter the timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal/expected behaviour for an ANSI terminal.

When you type <kbd>Esc</kbd> the terminal starts processing an eventual [ANSI escape sequence](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) (if you went on typing <kbd>[</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd> the cursor would go up).

So, after <kbd>Esc</kbd> the terminal waits for the next character in the sequence, if it does not belong to a know sequence then it stops processing, but both <kbd>Esc</kbd> and the next character you typed will be lost (they were part of an illegal sequence, and so the are dropped).

How to stop it? One thing you could do is change the inter character timeout for the terminal by calling for example `timeout()` from a program. See [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/timeout):

> While interpreting an input escape sequence, wgetch sets a timer while waiting for the next character. If notimeout(win, TRUE) is called, then wgetch does not set a timer. The purpose of the timeout is to differentiate between sequences received from a function key and those typed by a user.

Comment: Thanks! This explains it. I am using fish now.

Comment: bash doesn't use that call (and this is probably a duplicate, once you locate the correct information).

Answer (score 1):

Check your bashrc file and look for a line `set -o vi` and change to `set -o emacs` if there is still issues and your using a terminal emulator like alacrity that has its own built in vim mode you may have to change the emulators config also.

EDIT: This is the most common way it is set but if you have an inputrc file can also be used to set vi mode if you have an inputrc file the command there would be `set editing-mode vi` if that file and line exist just comment out or remove the line.

Comment: Thanks, but neither `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile` have this line. Running `set -o emacs` directly doesn't change it either.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Alacritty https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty

Comment: Also check if you have an inputrc file added to my original answer.

Comment: But i think you are onto something, when I type something, then press esc, I can use vim commands to move the cursor.

Comment: Alacrity has a built in vi mode that is what is causing this not bash.

Comment: You will have to go into the alacrity config located at `~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml` and at the end of the file are the default bindings they can be changed there.

Comment: Thanks, it might actually be alacritty. I can't find a lot of good info about their Vi mode, when I call `ToggleViMode` something different happens, most input is ignored. It might be a bug, or something else is going on.

Comment: Hm. It doesn't seem to be alacritty. When using fish as a shell the behavior disappears.

Comment: Then is bash add the line `set -o emacs` to the end of your bashrc see if that fixes the issue. Make sure you close the terminal and open  a new one after doing so.

Comment: Also verify the shell your using `echo $SHELL`

Comment: This seems to be expected behavior in ANSI shells (eg bash). I am using fish now. Life is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing escape followed by another key is (in many terminal emulators) handled as an alternatave means by which to send the Alt+Key keystroke.  For example <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  As such, it is not unusual for the first keystroke after pressing escape to be "lost" as it is in fact not being lost, but not sent in the manner which you might be expecting it to be.

Comment: Fish shell doesn't show this behavior...

Comment: This question is tagged Bash, not Fish.